# How can the user crop the picture completely freely

Tags: image, flutter, dart, crop, react-image-crop

I have a question about the `image_cropper` plugin... I want the user to be able to crop the photo himself and not have to use the preset options (3:2, 4:3, 16:9, ...), but I find no instructions how this works. I've seen it work on the internet, but I don't know how.

These are the possibilities that you can use up to now, but I want the user to be able to decide completely freely:

```
 aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
      ],
```

Does anyone know how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the the androidUiSettings with:

```
androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarColor: Colors.yellow,
          toolbarTitle: 'Bild zuschneiden',
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: false),
```